# Safari cannot browse Internet on macbook: getting "You are not connected to the Internet"

Tags: network, safari, wifi, internet

Was working yesterday in another town. Drove home.  Today, mac gets no Internet.
Can't browse any web from Safari.

My 2nd mac works great:  connects same WiFi router, browses ok.

Have tried...
Cycled mac's power.
Disconnected its Ethernet.

mac is new Apple M2.

Comment: What does network preferences say?

Comment: Delete and recreate the WiFi setting in Network Settings. Does that fix?